# Why message id from Firebase Cloud Messaging is empty

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating from legacy HTTP to v1 using the NPM firebase-admin module. But I have the problem that when sending the notification it doesn't give any error, but it doesn't return the message-id and the notification is not received on the device.

- Node version: 12.14.1.
- firebase-admin version: 9.6.0

Server code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./file.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const messaging = admin.messaging();

async function sendPush() {
  const message2 = {
    notification: {
      title: 'test title',
      body: 'test'
    },
    token: 'valid-token'
  };

  try {
    const test = await messaging.send(message2);

    console.log('--------------------------Successfully sent message:--------------------------');
    console.log(test);
    console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  } catch(err) {
    // Will catch both thrown exceptions as well as rejections
    console.log('--------------------------Error sending message:', err);
  }
}
```

When I send a notification using the sendPush function, I receive the following response in the console:

```
--------------------------Successfully sent message:--------------------------
projects/project-name/messages/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It does not contain the message-id specified in the docs and I am not receiving the notification.

Docs sample response:

```
projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages/0:1500415314455276%31bd1c9631bd1c96
```

Edit:

I tested the sendToDevice function (Legacy API) from firebase-admin and it works.

```
messaging.sendToDevice('valid-token', message)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('--------------------------Successfully sent message:--------------------------');
    console.log(response);
    console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('--------------------------Error sending message:', err);
  });
```

The push is delivered. **But send, sendMulticast and sendAll (v1 API) still not working.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was that the token coming from android was not correct for the new FCM versions. After updating the token generation in the apps, it has started to work with both legacy and v1.